# Is there a way to add Extras to Activity using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity

I'm doing unit testing using the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. Is there a way to add extras to the activity so when the activity gets to a line like this

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

it will return extras?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call [setActivityIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html#setActivityIntent(android.content.Intent)) in your tests setUp() method before ever calling getActivity, to change the intent that's used to launch the activity under test. This intent will then become the one returned by getIntent() in your activity.